# Error when using PictureBox from inside a class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a game ([FlipCard Game](http://bitcows.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/mzl.eelpdcdj.480x480-75.jpg)) and I've created my own class in which I have 2 fields.:

```
class FlipCard:
{ 
    // we declare  the attributes of the class.

    bool isTurned = false;    // to see if the card's been flipped or not.
    public PictureBox picBox; // my pictureBox


    public FlipCard(int x, int y, String pathToImage,String name, PictureBox picBox)
    {
        this.pathToImage = pathToImage;
        this.picBox = picBox;
        this.picBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        this.picBox.Name = name;
        this.picBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
        this.picBox.TabIndex = 2;
        this.picBox.TabStop = false;
    }
    // more constructors and functions here
}
```

(we have assignments to use a own-created class, so to use this is a must)

In my Form1.Designer.cs I have the following code where I try to add an object of type FlipCard.PictureBox to my controls. This is the code :

[image: Why do I get this error?]

```
private FlipCard drv = new FlipCard(500,100, "Koala", "FlipCard1", new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox());
```

Now, if I try to do this:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.drv.picBox);  // this in Form1.Designer.cs
```

When I try to reacces Form1.cs (main window) I get this error [image: this image]

And I do not know why (it is my first time when I try to add widgets to form from code and not do drag'n-drop)

Also, a couple of more questions:

1. Could I make PictureBox private and in Controls to add (this.drv.getPictureBox()) ?
2. If "Yes" to the above question, how could I control it? I mean, when I click on it it must "flip". Do I do this normally from `Form1.cs` with an event ?

Comment: Have you tried by declaring your FlipCard class as public?

Comment: You might consider making the `FlipCard` class a [custom control.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @hypnos i've tried now. Does not work, sadly

Comment: I will try to do what you say, @Johnny, but I have to ask: isn't there an easier way?

Comment: If you want to use the designer, you should make it a custom control. If you want to do it manually, you may have to abandon the designer. Ex: reate the `FlipCard` class in the `Form1` constructor then add the pic to the form.

Comment: try not to add this in designer code. create an eventhandler for the Load event of the form and add the control there...

Comment: you have to instantiate the class before using it in designer. Maybe your line `this.Controls.Add(this.drv.picBox);` is before `private FlipCard drv = new FlipCard`

Comment: I thought you must add every new item in the `Form1.Designer.cs` . So are there other possibilities?

Comment: Do not add anything in the designer.cd file! Handlers for stuff added in the designer should be added in the event page of the properties pane. other handlers can be added in code, best where you create the objects.